# Can anyone suggest me how to redirect in angular

Tags: angularjs, joomla3.0

I am trying to implement angular js with joomla. I made a demo on angular which is working fine independently, but when I merge the code with joomla it is redirecting wrongly.
Is it the router problem on Angular or joomla?

Comment: You should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with routes which is specified in you script i.e in script you have used absolute path but after merge its unable to link/locate the route.

Comment: And you should probably read [how write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)